# How does my site assign a specific class to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, class

I have this page here on my site (Which I have inherited from another developer) - http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/brand/

If you scroll down past the pink strip you will see the 'OUR WORK' section. This is a portfolio Custom Post type.

Currently the code to bring these through is this:

```
    <section id="scroll-target" class="wrapper">

        <?php
        $portfolio_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'portfolio-category' => get_field('category_to_show'),
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

        $portfolio = new WP_Query($portfolio_args);

        while($portfolio->have_posts()) {
            $portfolio->the_post();
            $post = new SeedPost(get_the_ID());
            $post->display(true);
        }
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>



    </section>
```

The portfolio items display as two in a row achieved by the class: 'item--two'

I'm looking to display these items in rows of 3 by changing the class of each item to 'item--three' which works when I edit it in the browser...

The problem is, I can't find where this class has been assigned in my code! I see it in the browser but as you can see from the code at the top - there is no class there.

I've checke .js files to see if I can see it being dynamically assigned, but I can't see where it is at all... Would anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE...

I think it might be coming from here, but I'm unsure where to alter to change the portfolio to display in three columns...

```
<?php

class SeedPost {

    public $post_id;
    public $post_type;

    function __construct($post_id) {
        $this->post_id = $post_id;
        $this->post_type = get_post_type($this->post_id);
    }

    function display($twocol = false) {
        global $post;

        $post = get_post($this->post_id);

        $cols = $twocol ? 'two' : 'three';

        setup_postdata($post);

        if($this->post_type == 'portfolio') {
            $overlay_class = 'item__overlay--portfolio';
        } else {
            $overlay_class = 'item--cat-' . SeedHelpers::first_category();
        }
        ?>
        <div class="item item--<?php echo $cols; ?>">
            <?php
            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                the_post_thumbnail('news-archive', array('class' => 'item--three__child'));
            }
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="item__overlay <?php echo $overlay_class; ?>">
                    <span class="item__cat-title item__cat-title--overlay"><?php echo SeedHelpers::first_category($this->post_type); ?></span>
                    <h4 class="item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <div class="item__brief">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <p class="item__link"> Read </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    static function load_more() {
        if(!isset($_GET['load_more_posts'])) {
            return;
        }

        check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');

        $offset = sanitize_text_field($_GET['offset']);
        $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'offset'    => $offset
        );

        $posts = new WP_Query($query_args);

        ob_start();

        while($posts->have_posts()) {
            $posts->the_post();
            $post = new SeedPost(get_the_ID());
            $post->display();
        }

        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $posts_used = (int)$offset + (int)$posts_per_page;
        $remaining = $posts->found_posts > $posts_used ? $posts->found_posts - $posts_used : 0;

        $response = array(
            'posts_remaining' => $remaining,
            'html'            => $output
        );

        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, check what's going on in the `SeedPost` class - specifically, the `display()` method of the class. My guess is that this class is echoing out the markup that you need to amend.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've just updated the question with a file i think I have narrowed it down too... does it look like its in there? I can see two, three, portfolio etc!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your section block amend the argument passed to `$post->display()`:

```
while($portfolio->have_posts()) {
    $portfolio->the_post();
    $post = new SeedPost(get_the_ID());
    // Pass in false!
    $post->display(false);
}
```

The `display()` method on the `SeedPost` class will then build the markup you need. This is set in the following line in your `SeedPost()` class:

```
$cols = $twocol ? 'two' : 'three';
```

...which means set $cols to 'two' if $twocol is true, and 'three' if $twocol is false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No prob...nice site btw!

Comment: Thank you - It's getting there! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the class is constructed dynamically so search for "item", "item--", "three",also search the SeedPost php class the items are generated there.

Another (not recommended solution...) is to overwrite the item--two properties within a container class and adding that class to the parent of the items in your case to scroll-target section.

```
.custom-container .item--two{
width:33.3% !important;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I've just updated the question with a file i think I have narrowed it down too... does it look like its in there? I can see two, three, portfolio etc!!

Answer (score 0):

you can add your own new

```
.item--three {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: .item--three already exists on the portfolio and news items being pulled through on the homepage: http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/ - I just don't understand where it is being assigned from... as it already exists I don't just want to overwrite iwith a new class - I need to understand were it is...

Comment: @ShaunTaylor: please replace the class .item--two with .item--three

Comment: Hi - That's what Im trying to do, @Subodh but I don't know where the class is as its not on the portfolio code

Comment: this is in style.css

Comment: I know the styles are in the stylesheet, but there is no class on the div. This is the question I am looking for the answer to

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 780px) {
    .item--three {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1060px) {
    .item--three {
        width: 33.333%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give some explanation.